# Zen subtheme: no sidebar on a given page

Tags: theming

The overall layout of the site is composed of a 2 column layout (main content area + right sidebar). I have a /forum section on my site and I would like to have a single plain area for it and its childs.

1. Adding a forum.tpl page containing no sidebars does the trick?
2. Another way might be to prevent *.sidebar-second* being loaded as a
   body class for a given URL (mysite.com/forum). Is this a clean way
   to do it and above all will it escalade to /forum/subforums ?

I'm using a 7.x-5.x zen subtheme with D7 and Advanced Forum as the forum solution.

Answer (score 1):

After some tests which involved using arguments in page.tpl and CSS trickery to clean up after, I couldn't manage to have a proper working solution.

Although I would have prefered to find a way to do this at a template level, easiest and quickest solution I finally found, was to use [Context module](http://drupal.org/project/context/)

Basically I created a simple context with a *Condition* on **path** option and a *Reaction* on **regions** of the concerned theme. Checked the sidebar I wanted to exclude Saved and it was done.

Good thing doing this through the Context module is that, it removed the concerned regions, but most importantly it removed also the corresponding classes from `<body>` which were the pain in the butt to begin with.